# console option in launch.json

Tags: terminal, console, gdb, output, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code, does launch.json file support "console" option to chose what kind of console to use with GDB, for example, internalConsole, integratedTerminal, externalTerminal?. Today by default application output is directed to external terminal..

Answer (score 0):

launch.json supports the following option:

```
        "externalConsole": true | false
```

Where:

- true: outputs to an external terminal
- false: outputs to the internal debug console

I haven't found an option for redirecting to the integrated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This works in version 1.81.0 of VSCode

```json
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```